# How to implement undo/redo and preserve the value on orientation change in android EditText?

Tags: java, android, undo-redo

I am using the [TextViewUndoRedo class](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/attachmentText?id=6458&aid=64580123000&name=TextViewUndoRedo.java) for undo/redo operations and it works but I want the value preserved after `orientation/onConfigurationChange`.

There are two methods in that class: `storePersistentState(Editor editor, String prefix)` and `restorePersistentState(SharedPreferences sp, String prefix)`, what do they do?

I guess, these are for `onConfigurationChanged` and implement in the following way, but they didn't work?

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    vNoteText = vEditNote.getText().toString();

    //----------------------------------------------------------------//

    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("unforedopref", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    editor = sp.edit();

    mTextViewUndoRedo.storePersistentState(editor, "undoredokey");

    //----------------------------------------------------------------//

    setContentView(R.layout.notepadmain);


    vEditNote.setText(vNoteText);

    //----------------------------------------------------------------//    

    mTextViewUndoRedo.restorePersistentState(sp, "undoredokey");
}
```

If you provide a undo redo technique which works `onOrientationChange` with example, it would be helpful.

Comment: can u explain the scenario what u want ? please edit ur question

Comment: Pls have a look on the class in the link, I just want to know what are the functions of two methods : 1)storePersistentState(Editor editor, String prefix) and 2)restorePersistentState(SharedPreferences sp, String prefix). I guessed those are to preserve the value after orientaion change of the phone. But the didn't work.

Comment: do not understand tell me ur requirement i'll give an answer if I can

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
  SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("unforedopref", 0);

  mTextViewUndoRedo.storePersistentState(sp.edit(), "undoredokey");
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

  SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("unforedopref", 0);
  mTextViewUndoRedo.restorePersistentState(sp, "undoredokey");
}
```

You need to save and restore state in lifecycle methods of your activity