# Second TextView shows NullPointerException

Tags: android, listview, nullpointerexception, textview

I'm trying to make a custom ListView item which contains one image and two textviews. They are supposed to line up horizontally (showing up side by side). However, the second TextView always comes out as null and causing the setText method to crash. I'm not sure why it is null even though I already set it so any help would be great. I am 100% sure the crash is NullpointerException as the logcat says so.

Sorry in advance if I'm doing not normal in my code as I just started out with Android development.

Here's my xml for the ListView item:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:id="@+id/category"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/message"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="19sp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:gravity="left|center_horizontal"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/datetext"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/message"
            android:textSize="19sp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|right"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And here's my `getView` method in my BaseAdapter class:

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list_item, null);
        }

        TextView txtAlert = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.message);
        // This is showing up as NULL
        TextView txtDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.datetext);
        ImageView imgCategory = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.category);

        // alert is a String
        txtAlert.setText(alert);  
        // date is a String; crashes here
        txtDate.setText(date);

        return view;
    }
```

Thanks!

EDIT: Here's the stack trace from the logcat if people are still looking at this post. ALSO, it is interesting to note any other `TextView` objects I add on will result in null as well. I have also tried cleaning and rebuilding the project multiple times and alas this doesn't work either.

```
08-31 05:32:19.695  24080-24080/com.ryan.myapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.ryan.myapp.activity.NotificationsActivity$DataAdapter.getView(NotificationsActivity.java:305)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2604)
        at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1253)
        at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1165)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16515)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:666)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:477)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16515)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5055)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16515)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5055)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1435)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:720)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:592)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16515)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5055)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2561)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16515)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2194)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1339)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1550)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1236)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5160)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:791)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:561)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:777)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5365)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Are you sure that `txtDate` is null and not the `date` string?

Comment: Can you show the stack trace from logcat output?

Comment: I am almost sure that you could not initialize the date string properly. It should be null, not txtDate.

Comment: Take a look on [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27241987/how-can-i-get-view-from-listview-by-position-and-set-text-to-item)

Comment: Can you try  txtDate.setText(alert) instead of  txtDate.setText(date) ? I fit does not crash then that means yout date string is null.

Comment: Hi guys, I won't be able to access the stack trace until Monday because I am away. But yes I am sure that txtDate is null. I checked during debugging and saw that date is not null. I put date in txtAlert and it was fine. Like I said in the post, date is 100% not null while txtDate is showing null.

Comment: Sorry forgot to tag @Hemanth

Comment: Very strange case .I checked your code..nothing wrong

Comment: @ci_ I just posted the stack trace from the logical output!

Comment: the only thing i can think of is that you are not using actually this xml, can you check that? if you have multiple layout folders(for diferent dimensions) check there also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the only thing i can think of is that you are not using actually this xml, can you check that? if you have multiple layout folders(for diferent dimensions) check there also

Comment: Thanks for the advice gmetax! You deserve the reputation! haha

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace :

```
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list_item, null);
```

by

```
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list_item, parent, false);
```

And there is no need to do

```
View view = convertView;
```

Next step > view holder pattern :)

Comment: Good tip, I will do it in my current and future coding!

Answer (score 0):

So everyone thanks for the help! Turns out gmetax from the comments section was right. For some reason it had a different id name from what I gave it. It showed the id's name as date even though I set it to datetext. If anyone could give me an explanation why this happened that would be great so this doesn't happen later in the future. Thanks!

Comment: So how did you fix it now? Was it just a typo?

Comment: It appears that it was a typo. Originally I set the second `TextView` object as datetext but when I checked the debugger, the view's children did not have the datetext object. However, it did have an object named date. I don't know how this happened as you see in my xml it is named datetext. This is also weird because I had cleaned my project a couple times so it should've changed (I think? correct me if I'm wrong). I'm still trying to make everything work as of now but I am not sure why this fully happened.

Comment: I made another doozy, looks like I had a large layout version of it too and I was testing on tablet. SUPER huge mistake/oversight on my part, thanks to everyone who tried to help.

Comment: i lost 15 reputation for not posting my idea as answer :P

Comment: @gmetax sorry dude! if you want to post it as an answer I can check you as the right answer.